# Count the number of countries . (This task is about multidimensional arrays and objects in JavaScript.)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The cities and their countries are given in the following structure:

```
let data = [
        {
            country: 'Serbia',
            city:    'Belgrad',
        },
        {
            country: 'Ukraine',
            city:    'Kiev',
        },
        {
            country: 'Russia',
            city:    'Moscow',
        },
        {
            country: 'Russia',
            city:    'Sant-Peterborough',
        },
        {
            country: 'Ukraine',
            city:    'Lvov',
        },
        {
            country: 'China',
            city:    'Beijing',
        },
        {
            country: 'Poland',
            city:    'Cracow',
        },
    ];
```

My solution is :

```
let arr =[];
let sum= 0;
for ( elem of data){
  arr.push(elem.country)
}
let  uniqueCountries = [...new Set(arr)];
console.log(uniqueCountries.length)
```

It works.

My question:

Is it possible to find better solution( not using new Set for example)?

Comment: Just do the _"is this city already in the array?"_-check yourself (simplest approach would be another `for` loop with an `if`).

Comment: Can you define "better solution"?

Comment: Andreas,  could you clarify what should be in code?

Answer (score 1):

Set has a size property you can use.
You can also simplify your code by using map inside the set instantiation, like so:

```js
let data = [
  { country: "Serbia", city: "Belgrad" },
  { country: "Ukraine", city: "Kiev" },
  { country: "Russia", city: "Moscow" },
  { country: "Russia", city: "Sant-Peterborough" },
  { country: "Ukraine", city: "Lvov" },
  { country: "China", city: "Beijing" },
  { country: "Poland", city: "Cracow" }
]

const set = new Set(data.map(o => o.country))

console.log(set.size)
```

I'm not sure why you wouldn't use a set here, but if you wanted, you could use a map instead:

```js
let data = [
  { country: "Serbia", city: "Belgrad" },
  { country: "Ukraine", city: "Kiev" },
  { country: "Russia", city: "Moscow" },
  { country: "Russia", city: "Sant-Peterborough" },
  { country: "Ukraine", city: "Lvov" },
  { country: "China", city: "Beijing" },
  { country: "Poland", city: "Cracow" }
];

const map = data.reduce((a, o) => (a[o.country] = 0, a), {})
console.log(Object.keys(map).length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set would be a cleaner way of doing it. You could clean up your code using map() instead of the for loop. Before set, you would use an object and loop over the list and get the countries.

```js
let data = [
  { country: 'Serbia', city: 'Belgrad', },
  { country: 'Ukraine', city: 'Kiev', },
  { country: 'Russia', city: 'Moscow', },
  { country: 'Russia', city: 'Sant-Peterborough', },
  { country: 'Ukraine', city: 'Lvov', },
  { country: 'China', city: 'Beijing', },
  { country: 'Poland', city: 'Cracow', },
];

var countries = Object.keys(data.reduce((o, { country }) => o[country] = true && o, {}))
console.log(countries.length)
```

to make your code cleaner, replace your for loop with map()

```js
let data = [
  { country: 'Serbia', city: 'Belgrad', },
  { country: 'Ukraine', city: 'Kiev', },
  { country: 'Russia', city: 'Moscow', },
  { country: 'Russia', city: 'Sant-Peterborough', },
  { country: 'Ukraine', city: 'Lvov', },
  { country: 'China', city: 'Beijing', },
  { country: 'Poland', city: 'Cracow', },
];

let arr = data.map(o => o.country) // replaces your for loop
const mySet = new Set(arr)
console.log(mySet.size) . // no need to make an array to get length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count countries using `reduce` method:

```js
let data = [
  {
      country: 'Serbia', city: 'Belgrad',
  },
  {
      country: 'Ukraine', city: 'Kiev',
  },
  {
      country: 'Russia', city:  'Moscow',
  },
  {
      country: 'Russia', city:  'Sant-Peterborough',
  },
  {
      country: 'Ukraine', city: 'Lvov',
  },
  {
      country: 'China', city: 'Beijing',
  },
  {
      country: 'Poland', city: 'Cracow',
  },
];

const result = data.reduce((a, {country, city}) =>{
  a[country] = a[country] || {count: 0};
  a[country].count += 1;

  return a;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```